# Javascript objects combining with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an issue with manipulating data in Javascript/jQuery and I could use some help.

I have an array of objects that lools like this:

```
var projects = [
  {title:'project1'},
  {title:'project2'},
  {title:'project3'},
];
```

I have another array of objects that looks like this:

```
ganttEvents = [
  {
    text: 'some text',
    start_date: '2018/06/13',
    end_date: '2018/06/14',
    id: '1',
    readonly: true,
    project: 'project1',
    category: 'scoping',
  }
  {
    text: 'some text2',
    start_date: '2018/06/14',
    end_date: '2018/06/15',
    id: '1',
    readonly: true,
    project: 'project2',
    category: 'scoping',
  }
  {
    text: 'some text3',
    start_date: '2018/06/15',
    end_date: '2018/06/16',
    id: '1',
    readonly: true,
    project: 'project2',
    category: 'design',
  }
  {
    text: 'some text4',
    start_date: '2018/06/13',
    end_date: '2018/06/14',
    id: '1',
    readonly: true,
    project: 'project2',
    category: 'scoping',
  }
  {
    text: 'some text5',
    start_date: '2018/06/14',
    end_date: '2018/06/15',
    id: '1',
    readonly: true,
    project: 'project3',
    category: 'testing',
  }
  {
    text: 'some text6',
    start_date: '2018/06/15',
    end_date: '2018/06/16',
    id: '1',
    readonly: true,
    project: 'project3',
    category: 'build',
  }
 ];
```

The project field in the second object will always be one of the objects in the first array.

I then need to end up with an object that looks like this:

```
source: [
    {
    name: "project1", // a project defined in the projects array
    desc: "scoping", // the category from the ganttEvents array of objects
    values: [
              {
                to: "2018/06/13", // the start_date from the ganttEvents array of objects
                from: "2018/06/14", // the end_date from the ganttEvents array of objects
                desc: "some text", // the text from the ganttEvents array of objects
                label: "some text", // the text from the ganttEvents array of objects           
              }
            ]
    },
    {
    name: "project2", // a project defined in the projects array
    desc: "scoping", // the category from the ganttEvents array of objects
    values: [
              {
                to: "2018/06/14",
                from: "2018/06/15",
                desc: "some text2",
                label: "some text2",            
              },
              {
              to: "2018/06/13",
              from: "2018/06/14",
              desc: "some text4",
              label: "some text4",          
              },
            ]
    },
    {
    name: "project3", // a project defined in the projects array
    desc: "testing", // the category from the ganttEvents array of objects
    values: [
              {
              to: "2018/06/14",
              from: "2018/06/15",
              desc: "some text5",
              label: "some text5",          
              }
            ]
    },
    {
    name: "project3", // a project defined in the projects array
    desc: "build", // the category from the ganttEvents array of objects
    values: [
              {
              to: "2018/06/15",
              from: "2018/06/16",
              desc: "some text6",
              label: "some text6",          
              }
            ]
    },
  ]
```

There may be several values at all stages for each project and there maybe projects with no events at all that need to be omitted from the source object.

Please can you assist?

**Edit:**

The background behind this is that I am pulling a list of events from a SharePoint list using SharePointPlus. This results in the ganttEvents array. I need to plug this in to the jQuery.Gantt library which requires the events to be formatted in a particular way.

[jQuery.Gantt](http://taitems.github.io/jQuery.Gantt/)

I am sorry but i am relatively new to Javascript (Python programmer usually) I have tried different methods of doing this to no avail.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself yet?

Comment: unclear requirement, many info missing here and there, can kindly explain the logic and requirement clearer ?

Comment: @Dean I have edited my question, is this the logic and requirement information more useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to group the array into an object. Use the concatenated values of project and category as the key. Use `Object.values` to convert the object into an array.

```js
var ganttEvents = [{"text":"some text","start_date":"2018/06/13","end_date":"2018/06/14","id":"1","readonly":true,"project":"project1","category":"scoping"},{"text":"some text2","start_date":"2018/06/14","end_date":"2018/06/15","id":"1","readonly":true,"project":"project2","category":"scoping"},{"text":"some text3","start_date":"2018/06/15","end_date":"2018/06/16","id":"1","readonly":true,"project":"project2","category":"design"},{"text":"some text4","start_date":"2018/06/13","end_date":"2018/06/14","id":"1","readonly":true,"project":"project2","category":"scoping"},{"text":"some text5","start_date":"2018/06/14","end_date":"2018/06/15","id":"1","readonly":true,"project":"project3","category":"testing"},{"text":"some text6","start_date":"2018/06/15","end_date":"2018/06/16","id":"1","readonly":true,"project":"project3","category":"build"}];

var result = Object.values(ganttEvents.reduce((c, v) => {
  let k = v.project + "-" + v.category;
  c[k] = c[k] || {name: v.project,desc: v.category,values: []};
  c[k].values.push({to: v.end_date,from: v.start_date,desc: v.text,label: v.text});
  return c;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

---

Without `Object.values()`, you can loop using `for`

```js
var ganttEvents = [{"text":"some text","start_date":"2018/06/13","end_date":"2018/06/14","id":"1","readonly":true,"project":"project1","category":"scoping"},{"text":"some text2","start_date":"2018/06/14","end_date":"2018/06/15","id":"1","readonly":true,"project":"project2","category":"scoping"},{"text":"some text3","start_date":"2018/06/15","end_date":"2018/06/16","id":"1","readonly":true,"project":"project2","category":"design"},{"text":"some text4","start_date":"2018/06/13","end_date":"2018/06/14","id":"1","readonly":true,"project":"project2","category":"scoping"},{"text":"some text5","start_date":"2018/06/14","end_date":"2018/06/15","id":"1","readonly":true,"project":"project3","category":"testing"},{"text":"some text6","start_date":"2018/06/15","end_date":"2018/06/16","id":"1","readonly":true,"project":"project3","category":"build"}];

var temp = ganttEvents.reduce((c, v) => {
  let k = v.project + "-" + v.category;
  c[k] = c[k] || {name: v.project,desc: v.category,values: []};
  c[k].values.push({to: v.end_date,from: v.start_date,desc: v.text,label: v.text});
  return c;
}, {});

var result = [];
for (var key in temp) result.push(temp[key]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi @Eddie, thanks for this. I have just tried it but i am getting this error: `TypeError: Object.values is not a function`.

Comment: @Morph_ByteSense Where are you using this? Nodejs? or Angular?

Comment: Worse than that I am afraid, this is plain old JavaScript with jQuery no framework at all, it is on an old SharePoint 2010 environment so I only have limited capabilities. I am restricted to old school JS and JS libraries.

Comment: @Morph_ByteSense I added a block of code. Not sure if it will work on your end. Please let me know.

Comment: that is fantastic thank you! It appears to be working, the only issue i have now is that the `name` part of the top level of the object is currently returning `null` which I am trying to figure out.

Comment: name must have be in `project` property